# I want to compare an arrayList object with a String, ignoring case. How can I do this?

Tags: java, object, if-statement, arraylist, ignore-case

Following code written in Java

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
    ordListe ol = new ordListe();
    ol.lesBok("navn.text");
    ol.leggTilOrd("hello");
    ol.leggTilOrd("Hello");
```

Is my main method. This is about reading from file and adding to a arraylist(dictionary). ''Hello'' and "hello" is supposed to be the same word, and in the code under, it should increase the count of that word.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ordListe.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ordListe.toString().contains(s))
        {
            if (ordListe.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s))
            {
                ord.oekAntall();
                System.out.println("'" + s + "' That word is found and there are " + ord.hentAntall() + " of that word now in dictionary.");
                break;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Ord ny = new Ord(s);
            ordListe.add(ny);
            System.out.println("'" + s + "' This word is added. " + ny.hentAntall() + " of this word in dictionary.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

So this is a part of my code. From the main method I add words like `ol.leggTilOrd("hello");` `leggTilOrd` is my method where the code right above is taken from. This is the part of the code that adds words to the dictionary/arrayList and checks if inputwords already exists. I have no problem with anything else than the specific `if (ordListe.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s))` part. If a word exist in the arrayList, I'm supposed to increase the count of that word. If not, I add the word in the arraylist (ordListe). The problem is that even if I add `ol.leggTilOrd("hello")` or `ol.leggTilOrd("Hello")`; with capital 'H', I can't get to recognize it as the same word even if I use the statements above. How do I do this, any other possibilites? This is my last possible effort, after many attempts earlier.

If there are anything questionable above, just tell me.

Comment: your logic has several issues, and the code snippet won't even compile; please try to edit your question with some more precise stuff. Anyway, the `contains` just inside the loop will not work case insensitive, and additionally it makes no sense to have it inside the loop.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention, but the code snippet is included in its own javafile called ordListe.java which is my "dictionary". It compiles for me, and I can add words from the main method in another "testfile". Anyways, I'm checking if the arraylist contains that string element, should I not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change both strings to lower case before comparing and then comapare..it will help you and is easier!!! Use toLower function and then compare

Comment: Even though this works, why don't equalsIgnoreCase work for me?

Comment: I am not sure but since you are using the toString() method which makes a string object may be creating a problem. try removing the toString and then check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
if (ordListe.toString().contains(s))
```

Because 1) you do not compare the lowercase or uppercase versions of the two strings and 2) you probably not overrided toString so it returns the items in the list as you probably expect. Put this function in your ordListe class assuming that your ordliste extends arraylist:

```
public boolean containsIgnoreCase(String item) {
     for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
           if (get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
               return true;
           }
     }

     return false;
}
```

Now you can call containsIgnoreCase to determinate if there is a specific item in the list ignoring the case

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but seems like a solution. I might try this out, but are there any other possible way of going around this problem, with base in my code? I.e without "contains"

Comment: I'm one of the TAs correcting this assignment. This is not the solution to your issue. (At the very least not directly). Your "ordliste" is not supposed to extend ArrayList. Also, be careful using code from StackOverflow in your assignment.  Copy-pasting it into your own code would count as cheating.

Comment: Ja trengte derfor en annen løsning/flere.. Er det andre muligheter her?

Comment: @erik-vesteraas, er det godkjent med 

if (ordListe.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))

for å sjekke store å små bokstaver?